# Keep "Backspace" key from being held down

Tags: c#

I am making something similar to "Peter Answers".  It's called "Adrian Answers" instead, due to that being my name.  But that is irrelevant.  This question has been answered previously, but I could not figure out how to apply this to my situation.  I need the backspace key to not be able to be held down.  If you hold it down, it should only register once in the program, but not any times after that.  By the way, I want this feature in textBox1.  Here is Peter Answers for reference.  http://www.peteranswers.com/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PeterAnswers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool secret = false;
        string answer;
        string normal = "Adrian, please answer my question:";
        int i = 0;
        bool secret2 = false;

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.OemPeriod && textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                i = 0;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                secret = true;
                textBox1.Text += normal[i];
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
                i++;
                answer = null;
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.OemPeriod && secret == true)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                textBox1.Text += normal[i];
                secret = false;
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
                secret2 = true;
            }
            else if(e.KeyData != Keys.OemPeriod && secret == true && e.KeyData != Keys.Back && Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift  && e.KeyData != Keys.Space)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                answer += e.KeyData;
                textBox1.Text += normal[i];
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
                i++;
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Back && secret == true)
            {
                string petition = textBox1.Text;
                if (petition.Length != 0)
                {
                    if (petition.Length > 1)
                    {
                        petition = petition.Remove(petition.Length - 1);
                        answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1);
                        i--;
                    }
                    else if (petition.Length == 1)
                    {
                        petition = petition.Remove(petition.Length - 1);
                        i--;
                        secret = false;
                        secret2 = false;
                        answer = null;
                    }
                    else if (answer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1);
                    }
                    else if (answer.Length <= 0)
                    {
                         answer = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space && secret == true)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                answer += " ";
                textBox1.Text += normal[i];
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
                i++;
            }
            else if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && secret == true)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (answer != null && secret2 == true)
            {
            answerLabel.Visible = true;
            answer = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(answer.ToLower());
                answerLabel.Text += " " + answer;
            }
            else 
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                switch(rand.Next(0, 4))
                {
                    case 1:
                        answerLabel.Visible = true;
                        answerLabel.Text += " Sorry, cannot compute answer at the moment.  Please try again later.";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        answerLabel.Visible = true;
                        answerLabel.Text += " Something seems to be blocking my mental powers...";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        answerLabel.Visible = true;
                        answerLabel.Text += " No answer.";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        answerLabel.Visible = true;
                        answerLabel.Text += " I find your lack of faith disturbing...";
                        break;
                }
            }
            secret = false;
            secret2 = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
            answerLabel.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            answer = null;
            secret = false;
            secret2 = false;
            answerLabel.Text = "Answer:";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Alright, sorry.  Thanks!

Comment: (Not related to your question, but you probably wanted the `rand.Next()` in your question to be between [1;5[, not [0;4[. Or lower indexes in your `case`s, would be nicer.)

Comment: What is "Peter Answers"? If know of the question that has been answered, put a link to it in your post so we can use it for reference.

Comment: http://www.peteranswers.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyDown and keyUp event to avoid repeat letter in textbox control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094962/keydown-and-keyup-event-to-avoid-repeat-letter-in-textbox-control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, and a `Boolean` flag:

```
private Boolean _backspace = false;

private void textBox1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = _backspace;
        e.Handled = _backspace;
        _backspace = true;
    }
}

private void textBox1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        _backspace = false;
}
```

The flag just helps the handlers know when the key has been held and when to allow it again.

Comment: If I hold backspace down, it now gives me an error- StartIndex cannot be less than zero.  This error occurs at this section of my code- if (petition.Length > 1)
                    {
                        petition = petition.Remove(petition.Length - 1);
                        answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1);
                        i--;
                    }

Comment: Or to be specific, at this line- answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1);

Comment: Is that because it's already empty?  If the `Length` is zero, then `Length - 1` is `-1`, and that's the error.  Check the length of `answer` as well.  You currently only check `petition`.

Comment: No, the length is more than zero.  I think as I'm holding down backspace, it's continually deleting characters from that string in the background, even if it's not deleting it from the textbox.  Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Peter-Answers  Here is an explanation of how the webpage works, similarly to my program.

Comment: Move what you have in `KeyPress` into a `KeyUp` handler.  Make a `KeyDown` just as I've shown.  Then you can remove the `KeyPress`.  `KeyPress` isn't ideal for this.

Comment: private void textBox1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  Into this event?

Comment: What should I do with your keyup event then?

Comment: Just add `_backspace = false` to the check you already have so that the flag is reset properly.

Answer (score 1):

Don's answer should work fine (and I upvoted it). As an extension to his answer, you could also abstract his backspace logic into a new `TextBox` control as such:

```
public class EnhancedTextBox : TextBox
{
    private Boolean _backspace = false;

    public EnhancedTextBox() 
    {
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(EnhancedTextBox_KeyDown);
        KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(EnhancedTextBox_KeyUp);
    }

    void EnhancedTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            _backspace = false;
    }

    void EnhancedTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = _backspace;
            e.Handled = _backspace;
            _backspace = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So, you would replace `textBox1` with it:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.textBox1 = new EnhancedTextBox();
    ...
}
```

Then move your existing logic from `KeyPress` to `KeyUp`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.OemPeriod && textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        secret = true;
        textBox1.Text += normal[i];
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
        i++;
        answer = null;
    }
    else if (e.KeyData == Keys.OemPeriod && secret == true)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        textBox1.Text += normal[i];
        secret = false;
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
        secret2 = true;
    }
    else if(e.KeyData != Keys.OemPeriod && secret == true && e.KeyData != Keys.Back && Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift  && e.KeyData != Keys.Space)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        answer += e.KeyData;
        textBox1.Text += normal[i];
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
        i++;
    }
    else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Back && secret == true)
    {
        string petition = textBox1.Text;
        if (petition.Length != 0)
        {
            if (petition.Length > 1)
            {
                petition = petition.Remove(petition.Length - 1);
                answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1);
                i--;
            }
            else if (petition.Length == 1)
            {
                petition = petition.Remove(petition.Length - 1);
                i--;
                secret = false;
                secret2 = false;
                answer = null;
            }
            else if (answer.Length > 0)
            {
                answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1);
            }
            else if (answer.Length <= 0)
            {
                answer = null;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space && secret == true)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        answer += " ";
        textBox1.Text += normal[i];
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
        i++;
    }
    else if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && secret == true)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
}
```

Moving it to `KeyUp` will prevent the string in memory from being deleted continuously as backspace is held, as you suspected in your comment under Don's answer.